Does Carrier Infinity older model have batteries and what exactly is the “OVERRIDE” sign for and how do I get it off?
My Carrier infinity thermostat was installed in 2011.
Seems to work fine since we bought the place but does it have batteries that need to be changed periodically?
Also, my thermostat has an “OVERRIDE” that ops up if I adjust the temp. How do I get it off and what does the the hours underneath mean, like does it stay the temp I turned it to for 2hrs or should adjust the hrs too if I want it to stay that temp.
I just want simple with know “scheduling” I wish I could turn that off as well.

read the user manual

consider new thermostat

Override means you have set the temperature explicitly rather than letting the program have control. To turn that off, put it back in run-program mode. For details see the user's manual for your thermostat; if you don't have a copy, it's probably available from the manufacturer's  website, or a usage video may be available on youtub.
If it has batteries, it will tell you when they need to be changed. Even my 2002-vintage thermostat can manage to display "LoBAt".
